# Xorg partially working for a font error

Tags: xorg, debian

in my Debian stable, when I execute:

`startx`

as normal user the Xorg server begin to work, but after some second I recive in console this error:

> FreeFontPath: FPE "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" refcount is 2, should be 1; fixing.

(I cut the stacktrace :))

When I execute Xorg as root, I haven't got this error!

I tried to:

1. change permission in same file ->useless;
2. reinstall XOrg -->useless
3. file config not existing? -> what?

I have see the doc in the Net but I found the root of the problem: for you, what's (better, what can be) the problem?

EDIT:

my /var/log/log.0 ---> http://pastebin.ca/1998075

Comment: Do you have *only* this error message repeated many times, or do you have other messages as well? Does X crash (it's not clear from your question)? If X crashes, upload `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` somewhere (e.g. on http://pastebin.ca/) and add a link to your question.

Answer (score 1):

No one ever found the cause of this error, nor any actual problems caused by it, so it was resolved in later Xorg releases by simply [removing the printing of the message](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/commit/?id=9113fa3de36e84bbae2727cace82b1cf0d709a86).

Comment: another resolved in this way: chmod =s -vR 1777 / tmp (http://forum.debianizzati.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=24470 in Italian language). I executed this command and, after startx, I receive an "unable to connect to X server) :) In this link somebody say to download the .deb by Ubuntu and not by Debian :(